# ASP.NET MVC 4 call a controller method from another controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am stuck on this issue. I have two controllers, UsersController and HomeController I am trying to call a controller method from UsersController from another controller (HomeController) by doing this:

```
UsersController usersController = new UsersController();
```

but I get this error: Generate constructor stub in 'CTHRC.Roti.Web.UI.Controllers.UsersController'

I do not understand this error.

Here is my UsersController:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using CTHRC.Roti.Domain.Api.Services;
using CTHRC.Roti.Domain.Model;

namespace CTHRC.Roti.Web.UI.Controllers
{
    public class UsersController : ApiController
    {
         protected readonly UsersService UsersService;

        public UsersController(UsersService usersService)
        {
            UsersService = usersService;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public dynamic Get(int UserId)
        {
            return UsersService.Get(UserId);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my HomeController:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebMatrix.WebData;

namespace CTHRC.Roti.Web.UI.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Default/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (!WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/account/login");
            }
            UsersController userController = new UsersController();
            return View();

        }

    }
}
```

What do I have to do to fix this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks. The reason I am trying to do this is because I want the data from the controller method.

Comment: Why do you need to instantiate UserController?  You can use a `RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName")` if you are trying to send the user there.

Comment: If you are calling a method from one controller to another, I think you ought to rethink your design.  Controllers have a lot of overhead and set up work, and there is no need to duplicate that.  Pull out what common code you want to use by both controllers and move it into a common area, such as a helper class.

Comment: Also, your code doesn't even use the controller you are initiating.  Is your example incomplete?

Comment: I am trying to do this because I am trying to get the data from one controller method in another controller.

Answer (score 0):

Your `UsersController` does not have a parameterless constructor, which is expected by the call site.

You can add one like this:

```
public UsersController() {
}
```

Otherwise, you must provide a `UsersService` as a parameter at the call site.

Comment: Controllers can have parameters in constructors.  It's a standard practice when using IoC. http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/117/Dependency-Injection-and-Inversion-of-Control-with-ASP.NET-MVC

Comment: when I do this `UsersController userController = new UsersController(UsersService userService)` I get two new errors 'UsersService is a type but is used like a variable' and ') expected' for usersService

Comment: Be careful, this is very basic understanding of IoC. Don't you have any other developer with most knowlodge of the code around ? you *can* do `UsersController userController = new UsersController( new UsersService())` but that *might* work it depends a lot on the project.

Comment: @user3723240: That's not legal c#.  You can't specify the type of a parameter when you call a constructor.

Comment: so how would i call this controller method from another controller to get the data??

Comment: Controllers are just classes that have methods just like any other class.  You create an instance, and then you call the method, just like you would do for any other class.  `instance.Method(arguments)`  Although calling on controller action from another is a very suspicious pattern that might indicate something is wrong with your design, there is absolutely nothing special about controllers that would stop you from doing it or make it different from any other class.